# Why does Apache server on UwAmp starts but stop immediatly despite having tried all the advices I have found?

Tags: uwamp

I'm using UwAmp from official website (portable version and up to date on a USB key) as a development server.
Until now, it worked perfectly on my old computer (Asus i7 running Windows 10).
But now, I replaced it for a new one (Lenovo i7 running Windows 11) and the Apache server starts but immediately shuts down. MySQL is still working.
I searched for solutions on these pages and noticed that this kind of problem often comes up. Although I tried lots of recommended solutions, it did not solve the problem.
I'm asking for help because I don't know what i am doing wrong.
Thanks to you

- I tried to change the port in apache config
- I tried to start Apache from [UWAMP]/bin/apache/bin/httpd.exe and obtained an error message: "the program didn't find the file "MSVCR110.dll".
- I tried to download this dll file but nothing changes
- I tried to install "vsc++ 2012 x86" as recommanded and still not starting
- I tried to replace my UwAmp software by reloading it from official site. It still don't work
- But now, trying to start with "httpd.exe", I have this error message "this application did not start correctly (0x000007b)"